# Create custom compass on map or move native button

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-maps-v2

I have tried to change position of compass button from top-left to bottom-left, but can't.

As I seen there are many suggestions to create a custom one and disable native button, but no one complete and normal example.

**How to add custom compass button on android map?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the position of built in Compass. Try this code:

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent();
        View compassButton = parent.getChildAt(4);
        /* now set position compass */
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) compassButton.getLayoutParams();
        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, 0);
        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 0);
        Resources r = context.getResources();
        float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        rlp.setMargins(0, (int)px,0, 0); // 160 la truc y , 30 la  truc x
        px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 30, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        rlp.setMarginEnd((int)px);

        compassButton.setLayoutParams(rlp);
```

Just play with `RelativeLayout` params and set it on desired location

Comment: Not sure, But i have implemented this in my project and tested with many devices

Comment: `Integer.parseInt("1")` because writing `1` is too easy? ^^ /// Let's look at `MapView` from the Play services library v11.4.2. The compass view has ID `5`. So you can save yourself all the hassle with `getParent` and `getChildAt` and just replace it with `(View) mapView.findViewById(5)`. Found it using the Layout Inspector tool. /// Remember, the code may change with each release of maps library. Make sure you test it with each update of the maps dependency. /// Don't copy-paste code without understanding it.

Comment: Don't forget to pu this code in a try/catch so that it doesn't crash as soon as someone modify the view hierarchy of Maps